# Mocked IList object injected in Mocked object renders IList empty

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

The situation is the following:

I have a suite of unit tests that execute tests in a structure of object. For mocking the objects on the test cases I'm using the Moq package.

The structure of the object that is being used is defined as:

1. `Context` object that holds an `IObject` (I won't declare it as ICollection because IObject is my particular implementation);
2. `IObject` is an interface that inherits from `IList<Class>, ICollection<Class>, IEnumerable<Class> and IEnumerable`, so it's a collection of `Class` objects but also holds other kinds of data, the collection being the main data.
3. `Class` is the type of objects inside the collection of `IObject` (to clarify)

On tests I'm using an extension method that bootstrap the `Context` and the `IObject` like:

```
Context and objectsOfClass come from the extension method call, Context is a Mock<Context>
var objectCollection = new Mock<IObject>();
var listOfObjects = new List<Class>(objectsOfClass); <- objectsOfClass is a list of Class
objectCollection.Setup(l => l.GetEnumerator()).Returns(listOfObjects.GetEnumerator());
objectCollection.SetupGet(l => l.Count).Returns(listOfObjects.Count);
objectCollection.Setup(l => l[It.IsAny<int>()]).Returns<int>((i) => listOfObjects[i]);
context.SetupGet(c => c.ObjectCollection).Returns(() => objectCollection.Object);
```

This issue I'm facing is, until the code reaches the `context.Setup` the `objectCollection.Object` property holds the collection normaly, but as soon as this call is made, the collection becomes empty and the `context.ObjectCollection` property is the same (mostly due to this being a reference). Because of this, it's not possible to use any access to that collection using Linq for eg. Even though any access by indexing works. To demonstrate:

```
foreach(var object in context.ObjectCollection) //iterates nothing
context.ObjectCollection[i] //returns the object at that position correctly
```

What I've checked is, if I use an actual object of type `IObject` object in the `context.Setup` then it works correctly, but the mocked object does not.

I'd like suggestions to what could be causing this and if the way that this mock is being set up is wrong or missing something.

Comment: You need to mock each interface, using `.As()`. From the top off my head, your indexer comes from IList<T>, while you set up the GetEnumerator() from the non-generic IEnumerable. The forach uses another interface's enumerator, probably IEnumerable<T>.